# Binary search with Random element

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, binary-search

I know that Binary Search has time complexity of `O(logn)` to search for an element in a sorted array. But let's say if instead of selecting the middle element, we select a random element, how would it impact the time complexity. Will it still be `O(logn)` or will it be something else?

For example :
A traditional binary search in an array of size 18 , will go down like 18 -> 9 -> 4 ...

My modified binary search pings a random element and decides to remove the right part or left part based on the value.

Comment: The best case turns to O(1) and worst case to O(N). The average case is harder to analyze.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, what is wrong in my average case analysis? I'm assuming you downvoted my answer because you found something wrong. EDIT: You just commented on my answer. Thanks

Comment: The distribution of the remaining array size is uniform after one selection. But is it still so after the second selection ?

Comment: @user1990169: The analysis of QuickSelect takes into account the number of comparisons to be made to find the rank of the pivot.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Umm.. Yes probably you are right. Average case is not so obvious.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt:

let `C(N)` be the average number of comparisons required by a search among `N` elements. For simplicity, we assume that the algorithm only terminates when there is a single element left (no early termination on strict equality with the key).

As the pivot value is chosen at random, the probabilities of the remaining sizes are uniform and we can write the recurrence

```
C(N) = 1 + 1/N.Sum(1<=i<=N:C(i))
```

Then

```
N.C(N) - (N-1).C(N-1) = 1 + C(N)
```

and

```
C(N) - C(N-1) = 1 / (N-1)
```

The solution of this recurrence is the Harmonic series, hence the behavior is indeed logarithmic.

```
C(N) ~ Ln(N-1) + Gamma
```

Note that this is the natural logarithm, which is better than the base 2 logarithm by a factor 1.44 !

My bet is that adding the early termination test would further improve the log basis (and keep the log behavior), but at the same time double the number of comparisons, so that globally it would be worse in terms of comparisons.

Comment: You don't say it but I assume you consider a 1/2 chance of the searched item being greater than (or lesser than) the pivot?

Comment: @Rerito: absolutely. I expressed this as "all remaining sizes are equiprobable".

Comment: What is value of Gamma?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Em... So, by choosing random element we make algorithm much faster? Then.. Why don't we use this approach in binary search and prefer middle=(left+right)/2?!

Comment: @SergeBreusov: possibly because this is only true on average, the worst case can be very bad.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume we have a tree of size 18. The number I am looking for is in the 1st spot. In the worst case, I always randomly pick the highest number, (18->17->16...). Effectively only eliminating one element in every iteration. So it become a linear search: O(n) time

Comment: That is the worst case scenario, but what happens in the average case or the expected case

Answer (score 0):

The recursion in the answer of @Yves Daoust relies on the assumption that the target element is located either at the beginning or the end of the array. In general, where the element lies in the array changes after each recursive call making it difficult to write and solve the recursion. Here is another solution that proves `O(log n)` bound on the expected number of recursive calls.

Let `T` be the (random) number of elements checked by the randomized version of binary search. We can write `T=sum I{element i is checked}` where we sum over `i` from 1 to n and `I{element i is checked}` is an indicator variable. Our goal is to asymptotically bound `E[T]=sum Pr{element i is checked}`. For the algorithm to check element `i` it must be the case that this element is selected uniformly at random from the array of size at least `|j-i|+1` where `j` is the index of the element that we are searching for. This is because arrays of smaller size simply won't contain the element under index `i` while the element under index `j` is always contained in the array during each recursive call. Thus, the probability that the algorithm checks the element at index `i` is at most `1/(|j-i|+1)`. In fact, with a bit more effort one can show that this probability is exactly equal to `1/(|j-i|+1)`. Thus, we have

```
E[T]=sum Pr{element i is checked} <= sum_i 1/(|j-i|+1)=O(log n),
```

where the last equation follows from the summation of harmonic series.